# Why do I get a blank material in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-4, materials

When I'm adding a material to a box in UE4, the material loses its textures.

I want to add this material

[image]

To this

[image]

After I'm trying to drag & drop the material into the scene above (like in UDK) the material loses its textures and does not apply:

[image]

When opening the material in Material-builder, the same thing happens: the material loses its textures and I've got these two errors on "Stats":

[image]
[image]

> [SM5] (Node TextureSampleParameter2D) Param2d> Requires Texutre2D
>
> [SM5] (Node TextureSample) TextureSample> Missing input texture

I've searched and found a thread where they say I need to save the material again to get things right. When I click the save button, I have this error:

> The current material has compilation errors, so it will not render correctly in feature level SM5.

*NOTE: Using DepthFade node + Lerp and changing the blend to translucent didn't resolved my issue.*

Any idea?

Comment: What do the errors say? Does the compiler error give any clues?

Comment: @Steven The error says nothing, just it has errors and it won't render correctly in SM5. Everything is in the question I could say about this.

Comment: I found out that not all of the materials lose their textures. Haven't found out the difference yet.

Comment: Is there any way to force UE4 to Compile Shaders?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your textures exists on the correct path. If you delete or move a texture the materials may throw errors.

Comment: It seems like everything is OK. The textures are on the correct path, I found out I need to hit **Ctrl+Shift+.** to compile shaders manually, it compiles, and then boom, the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Your texture samples in material have no textures inside him. Try to link textures to the material again.

Comment: This is a sample material comes along with UE4. In general, they have textures inside the material, but if I open them up or apply them they lose textures.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your answer the first time. Trying to link textures again doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the material to an Actor, just select it in the editor, select the StaticMeshComponent of any other Mesh and then you can select a material in the Properties Panel, just type it into the search box. 
If the Actor is a StaticMesh itself, you can select the Material in the Properties Panel directly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a folder with a bunch of materials that you downloaded and not a complete project.

The thing is that you cannot use them just by copy-pasting them directly into your project.

Do the following to be able to use them:

1. Copy the whole folder and paste it on the directory where your **VaultCache** is located. ( `Program Files x86 > Epic Games > Launcher > VaultCache`).
2. After that, open your Epic Games Launcher and go to **Unreal Engine > Library**.
3. If you look at the bottom there's a Vault tab. And under that should be the Asset Folder you just pasted in your VaultCache.
4. Press **"Add to Project"** and select the project you want to use it on.

There's a chance that you'll have to select an earlier version than the one you're using.